# How can I remap Control+e to Escape+Control+e in iTerm2?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, iterm2

I have set up a few custom keyboard shortcuts in iTerm2 to easily move the cursor around with the arrow keys, but now I'd like to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to be <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> because Bash 4.2 no longer auto-expands variables using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

I know I've done the first part correctly in choosing the keyboard shortcut to remap, but I don't understand how to look up the correct escape sequence (or hex codes) to send in the bottom section:

[image: Picture.png]

I reference they [keyboard codes](http://classicteck.com/rbarticles/mackeyboard.php) but that wasn't much help.

How can I remap this, and how can I look up the codes in the future? (No luck with Google)

#### Update

@db - thanks. To save others trouble I also found a cool util [Key Codes.app](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) which can be used to find key codes:

[image: Picture.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following: *Send Hex Codes: `0x1B 0x05`*

- `Escape` is ASCII 27 (it's often written as octal  `\033` if your shell doesn't know `\e`).
- `Ctrl-[Character]` combinations result in the ASCII code corresponding to the character's position in the alphabet. Well-known examples are`^H` for ASCII 8 (*Backspace*), `^C` for ASCII 3, *End of Text*, or `^D` for ASCII 4, *End of Transmission*, and likewise, pressing `^E` results in ASCII 5 — so that hex code needs to be sent instead.

You can even use this (I cannot imagine a real use case, but let's not care about that) to replace pressing `Enter` (*Line Feed*) by `^J`, or pressing `Tab` by `^I`. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) for more information about control characters.

Comment: @Daniel: can you take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/731427/how-do-i-send-ctrl-in-iterm2 ?

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I am trying to get the hex codes for other key combinations (`C-M-<char>`) in [this thread](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144481/sending-controlalt-char-to-terminal-in-iterm2), but it isn't clear to me what those hex codes would be. Your input on that thread would be extremely helpful