# How do I send Ctrl-; in iterm2?

Tags: emacs, iterm2

How can I send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> in iterm2 (emacs)?

There seems to be a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874190/howto-send-emacs-control-quote-c-via-terminal-iterm2), [here](http://offbytwo.com/2012/01/15/emacs-plus-paredit-under-terminal.html) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/445379/how-can-i-remap-controle-to-escapecontrole-in-iterm2)

These are close to what I want, but I am still unable to make it work.

Comment: Adapting my answer to the third link and sending `0x1B 0x3B` doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it, and realized 0x1B = ESC not control? (emacs sees it as M-; not C-;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I make these key combinations work is to go to the `Keys` section of the iTerm prefs and  create a shortcut for `^;` that sends some escape sequence, like `^[[aa` (you can replace `aa` with anything, but be aware that some things are mapped to actual keys). Then in your `.emacs`, create  a keyboard shortcut for what you want it to map to, like

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-[ [ a a") 'the-function-you-want-to-map-to)
```

Comment: What exactly do you have to do in iTerm here? When binding to `^;^ I have an action field I can set. Should I set it to "Send Escape Sequence"? And what should the next field then be?

Comment: Yes, use "Send Escape Sequence", then add the code without the `^[` (in my example, `[aa`). The `^[` (Control-[) control code is "escape".

Comment: Thank you, this works! When inputing an escape sequence however, iTerm shows `ESC + [ _your escape sequence_ ]`, indicating that it will actually send an escape key instead of ctrl key. (in my case, ESC seems to map to alt/`M-`) Just something weird.

Comment: Control-[ (control-left bracket) and ESC are the same thing, at least as far as a terminal is concerned (ESC is also called M- in emacs, and is often mapped to alt/option). You can test this in emacs. `ESC-f` and `C-[ f` both do the same thing (and in fact, if you type `C-[`, it should show `ESC` at the bottom).

Comment: Nope, not on my iTerm with `emacs -nw`. For me, ESC  is definitely the same as pressing alt/option (which I've never consciously changed), although it does show up as for example ESC-f instead of M-f.

Comment: Can we ask iterm2 to send whatever key Ctrl+; is for emacs? It seems a bit weird to map Ctrl + ; to something else.

Comment: @sgu yes, you can use something like https://github.com/asmeurer/dotfiles/blob/656198cb8920287992a856cb0f615f3c72536dfd/.emacs#L813-L869, then tell iterm2 to send the corresponding key code (for C-; it's `ESC " 5 ;`). See also https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html for a list of the official xterm key sequences.

Comment: @asmeurer That's very usually.   But I have a question for your .emacs.   When you call "define-key" to define the bind, why you quote some (eg: `(define-key keymap (kbd "ESC \" 5 R") '[S-return]) `) but not the others (eg: `(define-key keymap "\e[1;2A" [S-up]) `)?

Comment: @sgu as it says in a comment, I originally took that code block from a mailing list post. I don't know if there's any difference in the different ways of writing them. You'd have to check the keymap documentation in emacs, or ask someone who knows more about elisp (I'm no expert myself).

Answer (score 11):

How to bind a key sequence to the control key in Iterm2

1. Download the free application “Key Codes" from the app store. Install it from the link below and then open it.
2. Hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*some key*</kbd> in this case I’ll use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

   [image: How to get the hex code]
3. The code in the red square is the code we want to send to the terminal
4. Now map your key sequence using in iterm, preferences->Keys->+.

[image: How to map the command to the hex code]

5. This will now map opt+←delete to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> in the terminal, but you can use it to map any key to another one. I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> is a bad example for Emacs since it doesn't support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> but you can use this methodology for Emacs compatible shortcuts.

Comment: I don't think the unicode syntax you pasted is supported.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be
`Preferences` -> `Profiles` -> `Keys` --> toggle on the `Report modifiers using CSI u`.

Here is [the documentation of this option](https://iterm2.com/documentation-csiu.html) and [more about CSI u](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/).

There are some detailed discussions in this [thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).